# Prove that set is arcwise-connected. Function $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ with differential of rank $2$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and assume that $0$ is regular value of $f$ (i.e. the differential of $f$ has rank $2$ at each point of $f^{-1}(0)$). Prove that $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus f^{-1}(0)$ is arcwise connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a straight line $gamma\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^3$ such that $\gamma(0)=a$, $\gamma(1)=b$ where $a,b\in\mathbb R^3\setminus f^{-1}(0)$.
Let $T\subseteq\mathbb R$ be the set of $t$ such that there exists $r(r)>0$ such that a path exists from $a$ to all points $x\in\mathbb R^3\setminus f^{-1}(0)$ with $|x-\gamma(t)|<r(t)$. Show that $T$ is open and closed and contains $0$. (Closed is the tricky part).